# Not inserting element on call inserts after the entire execution

Tags: javascript, html, animation

```
function loadval() {
  r = Math.floor(Math.random() * load.length);
  console.log(r);
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
      var set = (i + 1) * 10 + j + 1;
      var x = document.getElementById(set);
      x.value = load[r][i][j];
      console.log(load[r][i][j]);
      sleep(25);
    }
  }
}
```

The element is not inserted one by one after the delay, all the elements are set after the whole function gets executed.

Comment: what is `sleep()`? you can do `setTimeout(function(){...}, time)`, put all the login inside the `function`, and set the `time` as `n * (i*9 + j)` where `n` is the interval time (i.e. 25 or 250)

Comment: I tried that too but it didn't work. Sleep is just a function that I created,

Answer (score 1):

why not use **setInterval** or **setTimeout** instead sleep(25)?

// repeat at 2 second intervals

```
let timerId = setInterval (() => loadval(), 2000);
```

// stop output after 10 seconds

```
setTimeout (() => {clearInterval (timerId); alert ('stop');}, 10000);
```